# Creating a dll with very large files

Tags: c++, dll, large-files

This is the first time I am writing in this forum, I hope someone could help me. I have been searching on the Web but have not found any answer related to my question.

I have a very large file (about 25000 lines) with thousands of definitions that must be used by another file

All these files (and about 600 more of them) are converted to .c files using a special tool. I am almost sure this conversion is made propertly.

If I create a.exe with all these files, there is no problem and everything works all right. Unfortunately, I need a .dll which crashes when I try to access to the very large file.

I have check that its .obj file is larger than 65MB so I have added the compiler command /bigobj as far as I have seen on the Internet but it didn't solve the problem.

I have also checked that the problem happens when access to the large file because everything works ok when I join both files (which is not possible in my development)

I am using Visual 2008

Could it be related to compile as C (/TC) or C++ (/TP) code? What's the difference between .exe and .dll that may make my program crashes?

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You've not been very clear in your question. What crashes (the compiler, the linker, your app)? In what way does it crash (is there, for example, an error message)? All of these things would help to give an answer

Comment: Oh I am so sorry. It crashes when I am using the dll (an .exe file uses this .dll). I have the typical windows error. When I try to debug the error it seems that a reference of a definition is missing (a pointer is set to null when it is not supposed to) this pointer should have information taken from the very large file. I don't know if I made myself clear, it is a little bit difficult to explain, sorry for that...

Comment: It might nothing to do with the large file. Just try and define the .def file correctly with all the function names that you need to access.

Comment: Hi. It is a very interesting point. My .def file is correctly defined with all the function names that I need to access. The error occurs inside of one of those functions. It uses an internal type which one of its fields is a pointer that is set to NULL when it should reference to a type of the large file. It is quite difficult to explain. Please, if it is not clear clear let me know. Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: Sounds like there is a bug in your code then. Without the code, it is very difficult to comment further.

Comment: Hi All,

I have finally found the problem. There is a bug in my external tool that does not initialize those pointers in some conditions and for unknown reasons (just great....)

Thank you all for your support

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, without the code not much can be said... (tho not sure if anyone would have the patience of reading 600 files each with 25k lines of code :) )

As advice, rebuild the exe and dll in debug mode, run the exe from MSVC, then put a breakpoint where you know it crashes. Next set a data breakpoint on the variable after you get its address from the watch window. ASSUMING the app does what it should correctly, then the pointer is set, but lost along the way; that means it should be triggered twice. 
Alternatively, try an assertion check.

Another scenario is because the variable is volatile.
Another scenario is the value is returned from a temporary value and gets lost...
And last but not least, the value is never set because of wrong\bad conditions...

If your problem is the crash and not the missing value, just do a null check and return the call if you really want to avoid the complication, however, I would recommend you find why the value isn't set. Your choice.